# Libgdx Preferences change in Android?

Tags: java, android, security, libgdx

Im currently working on a little Game for Android. First I saved the Game Score in Preferences but then i quickly realized while testing that you can change the Score for the Desktop Application at `%UserProfile%/.prefs/My Preferences`. So that rises the question can a user on an Android Phone change the SharedPreferences too? Currently i save the Score in a JsonFile. (I dont want to create a super complicated encryption, just want to use a way where its a bit harder to change the score).

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Yes, a user can change the SharedPreferences on Android, too. But I think it requires root access to the phone. I used the gwt crypto library to encrypt the data.